# how to retrieve a value from paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to retrieve a text from a paragraph like so:

```
<p id="userInput">1,2,3,4,5</p>

get 5
```

I tried:

```
var qq = document.getElementById("userInput").innerText("5");
                console.log(qq);
```

Comment: You want to "*get 5*"? On what criteria? To do what?

Answer (score 4):

use regular expression match

```
var res = document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML.match(/5/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the **slice()** method

something like this:

```
var qq = document.getElementById("userInput").slice(8,8);
                console.log(qq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.split();` to make it array of string and call it using `qq[4]`.

See my snippet *-"I use alert to show output"*

```js
var qq = document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML.split(',');
alert(qq[4]);
```

```html
<p id="userInput">1,2,3,4,5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because some Browsers support `textContent` and others `innerText` and some both, you have to make sure to check for both properties. Also note that `innerText` is a property and not a method.

Once you have the string, you can split it into an Array.

```
// Split the contents into an Array
var nums = p.textContent ? p.textContent.split(',') : p.innerText.split(',');

// Last item
nums[nums.length-1] // => "5"

// First item 
nums[0] // => "1"
```

If you can't guarantee the format of the text contents in the paragraph, it would be better if you did some kind of pattern matching with Regular Expressions like in one of the examples below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
//get text
var innerTxt = document.getElementById('userInput').innerHTML;

//convert it to array
var array = innerTxt.split(',');

//get last element in array, in this case "5"
var five = array[4];

alert(five);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the content of userInput you shod use:

```
document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML
```

Then if you want to get the 5th elementy then you can do:

```
split(",")
```

So the full code will be:

```
var arr = document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML.split(",");
alert(arr[4]);
```